# Yii menu linkOptions not working with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to display a CGridView in a CJuiDialog but facing some problems.
In my view, I create a menu item as follow :

```
$this->menu = array(
    array('label' => Yii::t('app', 'Afficher les participants ayant fourni cette information'), 
        'url' => array('Participant/ShowParticipantInfo', 'id' => $model->id_info),
        'linkOptions' => array(
            //'onclick' => "{viewP(); $('#dialogViewP').dialog('open'); return false}",
            'ajax' => array(
                'type' => 'POST',
                'url' =>"js:$(this).attr('href')", //array('Participant/ShowParticipantInfo', 'id' => $model->id_info),
                'update' => '#divForForm2',
            ),
        ),
);
```

Then I've created the dialog :

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
        'id' => 'dialogViewP',
        'options' => array(
            'title' => 'Liste des participants ayant fourni cette information',
            'autoOpen' => false,
            'modal' => true,
            'width' => 500,
            'height' => 300,
        ),
     ));
    ?>
    <div id="divForForm2"></div>
    <?php $this->endWidget('dialogViewP'); ?>
```

And my controller looks like this one :

```
public function actionShowParticipantInfo($id){
        $rows = Participant::findParticipantInfo($id);

            $result = array();
            foreach ($rows AS $key => $val){
                $result[] = array('id' => $key +1, 'value' => $val['NomComplet']);
            }
            $arrayDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($result, array(
                'id' => 'id',
                'pagination' => array(
                    'pageSize' => 10,
                ),
            ));
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){

            $this->renderPartial('_showparticipant', array(
                    'arrayDataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
                    ), false, true);
            echo CHtml::script('$("#dialogViewP").dialog("open")');
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

But but clicking on the menu item, there is any dialog diplayed. I cannot know why. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there should not be both 'url' and 'linkOption' attributes in an menu item. Either one.
Thru web dev tools you need to check **if you have ajax XHR upon menu item click**.

I'd recommend you [this extention](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ajaxmenu/) if you want to realize an ajax manu.

Even if you initiate ajax request the response cannot activate hidden dialog because on success you ONLY update certain div `#divForForm2` but the dialog window is still closed: `'autoOpen' => false`. I'd recommend incorporate opening dialog upon ajax success.

```
 'ajax' => array(
       'type' => 'POST',
       'url' => array('Participant/ShowParticipantInfo', 'id' => $model->id_info),
       'success' =>'js:{function(data){$("#divForForm2").html(data); $("#dialogViewP").dialog("open");}' 
        ),
```